# Keep track of child component values in parent without using emit?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3, v-for

I have a custom component called `HobbyForm` which is a simple form with two controls, a checkbox and an input, this component is being called from a parent component called `Content`, along with other similar 'form' components.

```
<template>
    <form>
       <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-1">
                <Checkbox id="isHobbyActive" :binary="true" v-model="isActive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <InputText id="hobby" placeholder="Hobby" type="text" autocomplete="off" v-model="hobby"/>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </form>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'HobbyForm',
    data() {
        return {
            hobby: {
                isActive: false,
                hobby: null
            }
        }
    },
}
</script>
```

My Content component is something like:

```
<template>
    <language-form></language-form>
    <hobby-form v-for="(hobbie, index) in hobbies" :key="index" v-bind="hobbies[index]"></hobby-form>
    <Button label="Add Hobby" @click="addHobby"></Button>
</template>
<script>

export default {
  name: "Content",
  components: {
    LanguageForm,
    HobbyForm
  },
  data() {
    return {
      language: '',
      hobbies: [
        {
          isActive: false,
          hobby: null
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
      addHobby() {
        this.hobbies.push({
          isActive: false,
          hobby: null
        });
      }
  },
};
</script>
```

The idea is to be able to add more instances of the `HobbyForm` component to add another hobby record to my `hobby` data property; but I don't know how to keep track of these values from my parent without using an `emit` in my child components, since I don't want to manually trigger the emit, I just want to have the data updated in my parent component.

How should I access my child component's data from my parent and add it to my array?

Answer (score 1):

In the current form passing parent data into a child component via `v-bind="hobbies[index]"` makes no sense as the child component (`HobbyForm`) has no [props](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-types) so it does not receive any data from the parent...

To make it work:

1. Remove `data()` from the child `HobbyForm`
2. Instead declare a prop of type `Object`
3. Bind form items to the properties of that Object
4. Pass the object into each `HobbyForm`

```
<template>
    <form>
       <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-1">
                <Checkbox id="isHobbyActive" :binary="true" v-model="hobby.isActive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <InputText id="hobby" placeholder="Hobby" type="text" autocomplete="off" v-model="hobby.hobby"/>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </form>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'HobbyForm',
    props: {
      hobby: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Even tho props are designed to be [one way only](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#one-way-data-flow) so child should not mutate prop value, this is something else as you do not mutate prop value, you are changing (via a `v-model`) the properties of the object passed via a prop (see the note at the bottom of One-Way Data Flow paragraph)

Also change the parent to:

```
<hobby-form v-for="(hobby, index) in hobbies" :key="index" v-bind:hobby="hobby"></hobby-form>
```

Demo:

```js
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      hobbies: [{
        isActive: false,
        hobby: null
      }]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addHobby() {
      this.hobbies.push({
        isActive: false,
        hobby: null
      });
    }
  },
})

app.component('hobby-form', {
  props: {
    hobby: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  template: `
  <form>
       <div class="row align-items-center">
            <div class="col-1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="isHobbyActive" v-model="hobby.isActive"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
                <input type="text" id="hobby" placeholder="Hobby" autocomplete="off" v-model="hobby.hobby"/>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </form>
  `
})

app.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.1.5/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
<div id='app'>
   <hobby-form v-for="(hobby, index) in hobbies" :key="index" v-bind:hobby="hobby"></hobby-form>
   <button @click="addHobby">Add Hobby</button>
   <hr/>
   <pre> {{ hobbies }} </pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so I made the changes you mentioned, but I still can't get it to work; I'm not that clear, with this solution I should be able to type in the input of each `HobbyForm` and have that value updated in it's respective item in my parent component's `hobbies` array?

Comment: Yeah, I think my linter is not allowing me to do this since it interprets it as me trying to mutate the prop, and will not compile

Comment: Error message ? I do not think this is something linter should mark as prop mutation as it is not. In fact I'm using it in full blown Vue CLI projects with ESLint without any problem. Also [the rule](https://eslint.vuejs.org/rules/no-mutating-props.html) does not list it as a BAD example...

Comment: I agree, however it does throw an error on my end even if I copy/paste your code, I'll check my linter rules and if I get it to work I'll get back to you